# Restrict site specific views to specific tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, ios-app

At the moment, as far as I can tell, in order to view only recent StackOverflow questions (or questions from any single site) from a single tag on the iOS app, I have to:

1. Select that site in the left drawer
2. Search for that specific tag (gah! brackets on phone keyboards!)
3. Change sort order

And that works, except that's how I want to use the app primarily. And doing so pins the search field in the header, so I completely lose access to the left drawer and the inbox, unless I hit Cancel.

And then if I want to recreate that view I have to go through all those steps again.

Would it be possible to be able to set each site's view to only show me questions from certain tags?

A more specific request, as I've used the app for longer:

Currently, you can edit the list of "Pinned Sites" in the left shelf, but it only lets you choose from whole SE sites. It would be awesome if we could also pin specific tags or groups of tags to this list, and have them display without the search bar, just like selecting from StackOverflow, Meta, etc. does currently.

Answer (score 2):

[I've written a feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220693/favorite-views-searches-in-ios-app) that is strongly related to this one, but I'd be interested in hearing whether you feel it would adequately address your request. Excerpt below:

---

Currently, you scroll to the top of the page to reveal the search bar. I propose hiding the search bar behind a search button to make room for three other buttons:

- **Favorites** store and recall favorite search/filter/sorts, *organized by site.* This serves as an alternative in spirit to tabs in a desktop browser
- **Filter** gives filtering options, such as featured, choice of questions-only or answers-only, unanswered, my tags, etc. Checkbox or radio for each.
- **Sort** after removing the options moved to Filter, is currently left with: Activity, Votes, Creation, Hot. The names should naturally match the desktop site: Active, Votes, Newest, and... wait what's *Hot* supposed to be?
- **Search** shows the text field we know and love.

---

A mock-up of the new **favorites** page:

[image]

---

I would rather use the app than the website, but the lack of quick access to the questions I *want* to see means I still leave a couple tabs open in the browser too, and spend more time there. I humbly feel **favorites** is the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach, previously as part of a different post that was too broad ([Don't go modal in app search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228682))

When I select a site from the sidebar, show the same search I'd previously used.

> [image: non-modal search]

Note, this is entirely dependent on that linked question being implemented, where the search doesn't go modal, blocking the sidebar and tab bar. Otherwise, you have to press <kbd>Cancel</kbd> to leave the site, meaning there is no longer any search to save.

---

Thinking about how to make this even better, the other side of this workflow would be that when you tap in the search box, the area above the keyboard is filled with recent searches on that site.

> [image: search history]