# Add Question Filtering

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

It would love to see the ability to somehow filter the questions an the active list. Its very cumbersome to 'thumb' through all the questions looking for one to answer. If filtering is not an option being able to have a favorites list and have them highlighted so they are easier to pick out.

**UPDATE**
I updated and found the 'tags' button at the bottom which is nice. Would be better if there was some visual cue on the 'Active List' to see a 'favorite' tag.

Comment: Are you using your "favorite" and "ignored" tag lists yet?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes I have a "favorite" tag list set up for SO. Should that be available to me on the app? I just updated and saw the 'tags' filter on the SE app.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220355/restrict-site-specific-views-to-specific-tags). You can show unanswered Q's in your tags, but it only sorts by question score (descending) so you're typically looking at lots of old questions. I still think the best solution is to be able to pin a "tag view" in the left drawer, like you can with specific sites.