# Don't go modal in app search

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

It's taken me months to figure out how to turn my frustration into a specific cohesive feature request. The problems lead to fundamental interface dead-ends, but are hopefully not ridiculously hard to solve.

Using the app is a very one-way process. Any time you need to back up, you lose your place. The sidebar and tab bar are only visible on the highest level, and to get back to them, your "progress" is forgotten.

#### This is most important in search.

Rather than bringing up a modal search window, allow access to the tab bar and sidebar inside a search.

> [image: sidebar access inside search]

This was previously a larger question which was too broad. It has been fractured and scattered to the wind.

Previously part of this question:
[Show realtime results while searching for tags in app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228829/show-realtime-results-while-searching-for-tags-in-app)
[Switch to Questions tab on selection from Tags tab in app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228830/switch-to-questions-tab-on-selection-from-tags-tab-in-app)
[Non-modal question dialog in app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228832/non-modal-question-dialog-in-app)
[Let me access the sidebar from asking in app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228833/let-me-access-the-sidebar-from-asking-in-app)
[Restrict site specific views to specific tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220355/restrict-site-specific-views-to-specific-tags/228831#228831) (answer)

Comment: I think breaking this up would definitely be appropriate, especially since some of these have duplicates already in [meta-tag:ios-app] :-)