# Show realtime results while searching for tags in app

Tags: feature-request, tags, ios-app

Forked from this request: [Don't go modal in app search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228682/)

When searching for tags, show the results as I type rather than waiting until I press <kbd>Search</kbd>

Note I'm not talking about searches based on tags, but rather listing the tags on the Tags tab:

> [image: tags]

Show that as I'm typing.