# Switch to Questions tab on selection from Tags tab in app

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, ios-app

Forked from, but entirely dependent on, [Don't go modal in app search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228682)

After selecting a tag from the tags tab:

> [image: tag search results]

Switch over to the Questions tab rather bringing up a modal search:

> [image: tag on questions tab]